# Magento: Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons

Tags: magento

i get this error in one category on my webshop. 
I see that this site: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/magento-install-error-exception-printing-is-disabled "has a solution" for the problem. However, i dont have any local.xml.sample or local.xml file.

Here is one of the error logs: http://pastebin.com/W65ziL5y
Seems like the error record number change for every refresh. 
Anyone that can help?

Comment: Have a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429 for some detailed descriptions on debugging in Magento

Answer (score 0):

Go to your

> magento root/errors/

folder and rename/copy from vanilla installation 
`local.xml.sample` to `local.xml`

This will show you exceptions on the frontend ( not recommended in production ).

Alternatively view your

> root/var/logs/exception.log

AND

> root/var/logs/system.log

If its enabled in under

> /admin/system_config/edit/section/dev/ -> Log Settings

to see all your exceptions and system notices.

Note that apache uncaught Magento errors will be stored in your apache log folder specified in httpd.conf

Comment: go to your root/var/reports folder and post their contents please.

Comment: Move them elsewhere and do another page reload

Comment: Appears your local.xml in error folder is empty but should have contents for error logging to write

Comment: Note that any changes that cause Magento to openly display any stack traces must be reversed. Otherwise you will be breaking **PCI DSS SAQ-D 5.6.6** by leaking error message information. 

Stack traces include neat things like your database credentials and other things that criminals need to know.

Enabling breaking PCI DSS without proper warning also tells you if a Magento developer is capable of producing secure websites. If they're quick to jump in and recommend anything but going and looking at the file saved in its standard place, watch out.